# Каким образом правильно подключиться через JDBC к SAS MetaDataServer?

Tags: java, jdbc, sas

Здравствуйте.

Пробую выполнить подключение к SAS MetaDataServer и получаю ошибку

```
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to establish a connection: Unable to return workspace. The client has connected to a SAS (9.2) Metadata Server (v1.0) when it intended to connect to a SAS Workspace Server.
```

код подключения

```
<%
    Connection connection;
    Properties props;
    Statement statement;

  /* SAS datasets can be queried with a SQL statement itself */

    String queryString = "SELECT username FROM MySasLib.users1 t1";

    ResultSet result;
    String id;
    String name;
    int i=1;
    try {
        // CONNECT TO THE SERVER BY USING A CONNECTION PROPERTY LIST

        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.sas.rio.MVADriver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("user", "user1");
        props.setProperty("password", "pwd1");
        props.setProperty("librefs", "mySasLib '/sas/dwh/user1/';");

   /* SAS libref and library name */

        //ACCESS DATA

             connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sasiom://server.inside.my.ru:8000", props);

        statement = connection.createStatement();
        result = statement.executeQuery(queryString);
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = result.getMetaData();
        int colCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        out.println("<TABLE border='1'>");
        out.println("<TR>");
        for (i = 1; i <= colCount; ++i) {
            out.println("<TH>" + rsmd.getColumnLabel(i) + "</TH>");
        }
        out.println("</TR>");
        String val = null;
        while (result.next()) {
            out.print("<TR>");
            for (i = 1; i <= colCount; ++i) {
                val = result.getString(i);
                if (result.wasNull()) {
                    val = nbsp;
                }
                out.print("<TD>" + val + "</TD>");
            }
            out.println("</TR>");
        }
        out.println("</TABLE>");
        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        out.println("error " + e);
    }
%>
```

Подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metadata Server не предназначен для доставки данных и такого API не предоставляет.  Вместо этого, вы должны подключаться к Workspace Server.

Соответственно, укажите в JDBC URI порт Workspace Server.